# XAMPP parallel with Apache

Tags: apache, xampp, archlinux

I have on my PC "normal" Apache (with PHP and MySQL) installed, and I want to run XAMPP in parallel. I changed ports of HTTP(to 81), MySQL(to 3307) and SSL(to 4433) in the XAMPP config, but XAMPP says when I want to start it:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

so only the FTP server starts (which I don't need), and the web server won't start. I really don't know, where the problem is.

I'm using Archlinux x86_64

Comment: I found, that I can stop Apache and MySQL server, then start XAMPP and then start Apache and MySQL server again, but is is possible to do it more easily?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you should read: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP, it is better, and more professional.

Comment: Summarize the useful points from the link in the answer itself